# I have a huge white space on the left of the arabic version of the site

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a huge white space on the left of the arabic version of the site check it out: [here](http://delmonoptic.com/ar/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D8%A6%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A9/).

note: the english version is fine.

I have the very same site without the white space [here](http://delmonoptic.tecmood.com/ar/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D8%A6%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A9/) but am not sure if there have been any changes.

Please help me get rid of it.

Comment: I don't see the white space. What browser are you using?

Comment: already fixed. thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

line 18 rtl.css -> I see the issue

```
.metaslider {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

change ltr to rtl

Answer (score 0):

I checked out the link . The problem might be with the alignment of the text you can use

dir="rtl" to fix  it .

You can obtain more info here:
https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir

Hope it helps :)